# Restoring state of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment F attached on Activity A. When another activity becomes front-activity it is called `onSaveInstanceState`. I've overrided that function and it looks like:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
 saveState_to_outstate
}
```

Now, when the Fragment F is front again it is called `onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)`. I would like to restore previously saved state but I cannot because `savedInstanceState` is null though it was written before in `onSaveInstanceState`.

Why it happened?

Comment: please edit your question and add the code where you are "attaching" Fragment F to Activity A

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't do anything .. specifically `saveState_to_outstate` does nothing, you need to use the `outState` `Bundle` from the method argument to save data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore Fragment F with previous Data. As according to my knowledge you should perform inside `onViewStateRestored()` method of Fragment.

OnViewStateRestored (Bundle) tells the fragment that all of the saved state of its view hierarchy has been restored.
you Should visit this link for your reference:[Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Method A: You can pass the data from Activity A to Fragment F by bundle or intent. it's similar to usage of saving instance.
[Send data from activity to fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

MethodB: You can only use following function with `onCreate()` at the same place, either fragment F or Activity A.

`public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
   outState.putInt("STATE_NAME", 123);//123 is the data you gonna save
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);//Don't forget to put this
}`

MethodC: Use hardcode-like SharePreference [Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example) ,it's also like the bundle and intent, and it won't be effected by Activity or fragment life periods.